# LC circuit VS CL circuit low pass filter

Tags: filter, emc, switching, low-pass, switching-regulator

Are these two topologies for LC low pass filter equivalent?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYCgP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMQJNx.png)</sup>

I mean, if I got a switching source, is it the same using an LC compared to a CL series connection to smooth out the voltage? I am referring to long run behaviour after the very first duty cycles; of course I can expect that the configurations will show phase difference as voltage step response.

Do the very same LC equations work for the CL configuration? Is cutoff frequency calculated the same way?
Moreover, are there any specific EMI considerations? In the first circuit, the load without GND reference could surely be a risk for EMI, compared to the second circuit. What about adding a decoupling capacitor between the low side of the load and GND?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMz2kz.png)</sup>

Comment: Where are the ground connections?

Comment: Obiously I forgot to add the GND. It's on the negative side of the square wave source.

Comment: The load is grounded in the second circuit. In the first circuits it floats on top of the inductor. In the third circuit it is bound to a decoupling capacitor to ground.

Comment: What's wrong with using the 2nd circuit?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the second circuit. But I want to understand the difference between the different topologies.

Comment: Its not a low pass filter. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit

Comment: @JImDearden Why it is not a low pass? And what would the effect on VLoad be?

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to understand if you draw C2 in parallel to L1.

Comment: By EMI do you mean ground bounce? The ground bounce should have no effect because any noise at the ground is transferred to your supply as well. It is only if the supply is regulated to remove any disturbance in supply, can ground bounce create a problem. Also to remove ground bounce, the bypass cap should be placed at the ground node. Also, since the circuit is just a series combination of LC they should be equivalent.